# ls: Do not show directories that match same pattern in wildcard searches, only files

Tags: shell, files, directory, ls, wildcards

Supposing I have something like the following, a typical business PC situation:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 whatever whoever       3 Oct  3 16:40 invoices2009
drwxr-xr-x 1 whatever whoever       4 Oct  3 16:40 invoices2010
drwxr-xr-x 1 whatever whoever       2 Oct  3 16:40 invoices2011
-rwxr-xr-x 1 whatever whoever  440575 Oct  3 16:40 tax2010_1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 whatever whoever  461762 Oct  3 16:40 tax2010_2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 whatever whoever  609123 Oct  3 16:40 tax2010_3
```

Now let's be lazy and just type:

```
$ ls -l *2010*
```

Supposing that there *is* something in the invoices2010 directory, it won't work as expected. Since the *directory name* contains the *2010* year as well, `ls` will also list the files in *invoices2010*, although I only want to list those in the current directory.
Even funnier: imagine the tax2010* files weren't there at all and there were not those three directories as in the example, but 50 of them. Yes I've tried it out: `ls` will not even *indicate* which files are in which directory, but simply list them top-down, just as if all files resided in the current directory (unless you explicitly specify the `-R` option, certainly I do know that)

Plus, I know that I can do this with `find`, too, but is there also any way to accomplish this task with a plain `ls` one-liner (which, obviously, has a far less complicated syntax)?

Comment: What shell is it? Bash?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like your question is "How to list files by pattern excluding directories with `ls` only".

There is no way to do it with pure `ls`. You can combine `ls` + `grep` like:

```
ls -ld *2010* | grep -v '^d'
```

However it's much better to use `find` for that:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*2010*"
```

Comment: Ah! I should have thought about `grep`ing for `^d`. I didn't think of that, obviously. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`ls -dlp *2010*` would be a good start to the solution, but it depends what you want the output to look like.

Comment: No, it would not be a good start at all. In my example, I wish to have the tax* files listed, whilst your solution would simply list _all directories that match the pattern without showing their file content_. That's something completely different.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want the output to look like. You said you only want files in the current directory to be listed.
Try also ls -ldp *2010

Comment: @syntaxerror - I don't understand your question either. You did ask for 'only files in the current directory', which is what this answer does. But your comment appears to want the inverse? All files in all sub-directories? Can you edit your question to be clearer?

Comment: There is actually nothing much to "edit". So again: I want the tax* files in the current directory to be listed, but the directory "invoices2010" _which resides in the same working directory_ and which also matches the given `*2010*` wildcard pattern should be skipped in the listing.

Comment: Not what the author asked, but it is what I needed when Google found this answer for me. +1.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to selectively filter out directories using only `ls`. You need either `find` or `ls | grep`, as described in [rush's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50008/22651) . But for your specific example, to answer the question you asked in [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50004/ls-do-not-show-directories-that-match-same-pattern-in-wildcard-searches-only-f/50009#comment70061_50005):

> So again: I want the tax* files in the current directory to be
>   listed, but the directory "invoices2010" which resides in the same
>   working directory and which also matches the given *2010* wildcard
>   pattern should be skipped in the listing.

you can do

```
ls -l --ignore='invoices*' *tax2010*
```

which filters out anything matching the `ignore` shell pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Use zsh…

```
ls -l *2012*(.)
```

The [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `.` means regular files only.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use grep with ls,

In bash you could show files that have a "2010" in its name but not staring with a number:

`ls -l *[!0-9]2010*`

Answer (score 0):

There are reasons not to `grep` against `ls` but if you disregard them, this works.  Use the `ls` command as an input array, call `ls -ld` on each entry piped to `grep` to exclude directories with the output sent to null, and if successful echo the original input:

```
for list in `ls` ; do ls -ld $list | grep -v ^d > /dev/null && echo $list ; done ;
```

You can invert the grep and conditional output, same results:

```
for list in `ls` ; do ls -ld $list | grep ^d > /dev/null || echo $list ; done ;
```

EDIT: My bad, this works without a pattern match, but if you add a wildcard search as in the OP above, *and* you have a directory that matches the pattern, the output still includes system messages so you would need to filter further to get just the file list.

EDIT again: fixed backslashes on /dev/null.

Comment: `\dev\null`?!?!